# Is it possible to change folder where JBoss 5.1 writes its boot traces?

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

By default **JBoss 5.1** writes boot traces to **$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/log folder**.
Is it possible to change location for boot traces?
Boot traces - traces in file **boot.log**.

Comment: what do you mean by "boot trace"? Which log file are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log4j bootstrap log is configured, rather bizzarely, from the `log4j.properties` inside `bin/run.jar`. You need to override that configuration with your own.

See [this page](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossBootLogging) for a description of how it works, but essentially you can supply your own boot log4j config by using a system property, e.g.

```
run.bat -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.properties
```

Once the bootstrap has finished, JBoss will switch to the `conf/jboss-log4j.xml` configuration as before.

Comment: The simplest way - just redefine property jboss.server.log.dir.

Comment: Yes, but that will move *all* the logs, not just the boot log